# How can I tell Visual Studio to use a custom editor to open a file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm implementing a custom editor for Visual Studio. I'm registering it like this:

```
[ProvideEditorExtension(typeof(MyEditorType), ".myext", 99, NameResourceID = 106)]
```

When the package of the extension is initialized I register the editor instance like this:

```
RegisterEditorFactory (new MyEditorType());
```

The registration seems to work, since I can see my editor in the list shown by the Open With... command, and I can open the file in my editor if I select it there. However, when I double-click on the file in the Solution Explorer it always opens the text editor, event though my custom editor is set as default in the Open With dialog.

What's I'm missing?

Comment: Which extension are you registering for? Is there another editor factory active for that extension too?

Comment: The extension is axml. AFAIK there is no other editor factory for that extension.

Comment: Have you tried to set the `EditorFactoryNotify` property of the `ProvideEditorExtension` attribute to `true`? This would associate your editor factory with the file type...

Comment: Can you share code of _MyEditorType_ ? or at least the _CreateEditorInstance_ function?